# Twitter4j Listen to tweets from a particular user

Tags: java, twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api

I want to perform certain actions when a particular user tweets something. So is it possible in twitter4j to listen to tweets from a particular user account and handle the event?

I know what the answer would be: read streaming api. But I think its too vast for my purpose and I only want to listen to tweets from a particular account.Hence I am asking it here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should try the sample code:

```
    TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(new ConfigurationBuilder().setJSONStoreEnabled(true).build()).getInstance();

    twitterStream.setOAuthConsumer(_consumerKey, _consumerSecret);
    AccessToken token = new AccessToken(_accessToken, _accessTokenSecret);
    twitterStream.setOAuthAccessToken(token);

    StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() {
        public void onStatus(Status status) {
            logger.info(DataObjectFactory.getRawJSON(status));

            //do your action here
        }

        ...
    };

    twitterStream.addListener(listener);

    FilterQuery query = new FilterQuery();
    query.follow(new long[] { _twitterUserId });
    twitterStream.filter(query);
}
```

Comment: I guess the twitterStream listens to random samples of tweetts. So I am not sure that whether this code would listen to all tweets from a user. It might miss out some tweet. What d u say about that?

Comment: it listens tweets from a particular user that have id - twitterUserId.

Comment: You can apply (and pay for) the twitter firehose to get access to everything in a streaming manner. They're fairly easy about granting access.

Comment: @hd1 cant i listen to the accounts I follow? I think this is a basic thing for the twitter api, although I havent read more about it?

Comment: @LTC I tried your code and listened to another account belonging to me. It is working and getting its tweets.But i need this code for an application which should not miss any of the tweets. So can u find a suitable evidence that your solution wont miss a single tweet from an account? (According to http://blog.falcondai.com/2013/06/666-and-how-twitter-samples-tweets-in.html sampling is around 1-2%)

Comment: @rahulserver Within their API policies, you can do whatever you wish, but as you noted, they make 1-2% of the tweets available publicly and how they determine that is anyone's guess.

Comment: The answer is working fine and i havent missed any tweet so far.Thanks bro!

Comment: This solution not streaming protected users. Need to use UserStream instead.